# Operation time out in Exchange Web service

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I wrote a application using Exchange Web Service to read the mail item and stores the From, To etc... to the Database.
I started to run the application as a job in Sql server.
Initially it was running successfully. But after 3 days I am getting error message like

```
'The request failed. The operation has timed out'
```

Please help. What would be cause of the problem

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem? I'm having the same problem, my web service is dying after 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how often you try to talk to the exchange web service. Maybe the exchange server is overloaded with work. Maybe the amount of data that you're trying to access is too much and/or filtering is taking too long.

It's simple, you're talking to a web service and whatever it is that you're telling it to do is taking longer than the allowed timeout values specified in the web service's configuration and/or client configuration.

Try finding where the timeout values are stored and increase them.